# Fixed Point Iteration for Linear Systems

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

We have the following linear system:

$\quad Ax=b$

Suppose $A$ is perturbed so that we are actually solving $(A+E)\;\hat x=b$

where $\hat A = A+E$

The notes I'm reading say to think of $x$ as the fixed point iteration for an iteration:

$\quad \hat A\;x_{k+1}-E\;x_k=b$

I understand how the iterative refinement formula is derived using residuals.
I'm looking for clarification on how fixed-point iteration for linear systems formula is derived?

Comment: That can't be right, because in the limit you'll have $x_{k+1}=x_k=x$ but then $Ax-Ex=b$ which is not the equation you want. Maybe it should be $+Ex_k$?

Comment: @Ian I've edited my post to define $\hat A$. Note that it's not $Ax−Ex=b$ but $\hat Ax−Ex=b$. That is,$\hat A$ is $A$ perturbed by $E$.

Comment: Nonetheless, if $x$ if a fixed point of the mapping "$x \mapsto y$ such that $\hat{A}y-Ex=b$", then $Ax=b$, not $(A+E)x=b$. So it still seems amiss. In any case, the simplest practical iteration of this type is the Jacobi iteration (where $A$ is diagonal and $E$ is in principle arbitrary), you might look that up and then write it in a more general form to see how to write things correctly.